# Using samsung galaxy s7 navigation buttons with ADB

Tags: android, adb, samsung-galaxy

How can I use the navigation buttons on my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge through the Android Debug Bridge? I have tried to mess around with the `input` command using the *touchnavigation* source, but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is my first time using ADB, so im a bit of a noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adb shell input "KEYCODE_HOME"
adb shell input "KEYCODE_BACK"
```

rest of keycodes: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent